# Excel Ledger with running Balance using sumif

Tags: excel-formula

I want to make a ledger with multiple currency, problem i m getting is in running balance

[image: Here is pic of my sheet]

Comment: Can you share some of your formulas? What have you tried to solve you problem?

Comment: I would look at defining a cell or cells with the current exchange rate, then calling those in the calculations as necessary. Then you only need to update the currency exchange rate daily for example and only in one cell...

Comment: HI, thanks for quick reply, i m using this formula

SUMIF(C6,$D$1, E6)-SUMIF(C6,$D$1, F6)+SUMIF(C6,$D$1, G5)

i have uploaded a file

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=21837846868221563709

thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your G6 cell.. then drag downwards.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(G5),G5,0)+IF([@Currency]=$D$1,[@Debit],0)-IF([@Currency]=$D$1,[@Credit],0)`

You may edit the `$D$1` & `G5` to match the other currency/column.

idea : if top = value, copy. If debit/credit = have value, add/minus from the copied value.

Please share if it solves (or not)..

Comment: thanks a lot, it completely solved my problem, i really appreciate  that.

Comment: appreciate if you may click on the tick beside this answer post . ( :